Маршрутизация через несколько VPN со статичными IP
Допустим я арендовал несколько VPN со статичными IP, по одному IP для подключения к одному заранее известному сайту (ip1 на google.com, ip2 на amazon.com и т.д.). На ubuntu 24.04 мне нужно к этим всем впн подключиться одновременно, т.е. установить с ними соединение и маршрутизовать запросы в зависимости от сайта. Т.е. запросы к google.com должны идти через впн с ip1, к amazon.com через впн с ip2, ..., а все остальные запросы должны идти без впн сразу в сеть. Как мне это сделать? Точнее спросить - где мне найти гайд по такому подключению?
Это приближенная задача к той которая есть на самом деле, поэтому мне не нужны альтернативные решения, мне нужно именно установить подключение с разными впн и пускать определённый трафик через них.
Я только разбираюсь как устроено подключение с помощью openvp, например что можно выполнить команду  openvpn OpenVPN_config_file.ovpn и весь трафик перенапрвится через впн.
